# Can someone please explain to me how to insert DROP ZONE multiple image details to a single row on MSQL

Tags: php, mysql, upload, dropzone.js

The following code insert each image details on its own separate row. I want to insert the details in the columns of a single row. how would I do this ?

```
//upload.php
<?php
require "sys_connection.php"; 
require "sys_houses_connection.php";
$storeFolder = 'uploads';   //2

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $unx = "sng".time().$pn.mt_rand();
    $phtpth_1=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $phtname_1= $unx.basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $dir='uploads';
    $movepht_1= move_uploaded_file($phtpth_1,$dir."/".$phtname_1);
    //insert file information into db table
    mysqli_query("INSERT INTO files (file_name, uploaded)     VALUES('uploads/$phtname_1','$phtname_1')");
}
```

Comment: What is you table schema ? how many image is allowed in one row ?

Comment: I want to upload 3 images in one row.

Comment: Again, do you want to put 3 image information in on row (what is the table structure ), or do you want to handle the upload of 3 images in one script ?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else encounters my issue, here is the solution.

In order to fetch the files, just extract the array.

```
echo $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']['0'];
echo $_FILES['file']['name']['1'][0];

echo $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']['1'];
echo $_FILES['file']['name']['1'][1];

E.T.C...
```